# How to share multiple images into one post for instagram?

Tags: android, instagram

I used instagram integration within my android app.
My requirement is to share multiple images into one post.
This is new feature for instagram itself.

As far as I know instagram only supports intent parsing for data sharing.

```
 Intent instagram = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        instagram.setType("image/*");
        instagram.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        instagram.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "caption:goes here");
        instagram.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
        startActivity(instagram);
```

I tried using parceable arraylist for multiple uris.

Comment: were you able to find any solution to this?

Comment: @AmitBarjatya No, instagram has not provided any means to achieve this

Comment: Is it a achievable one?

Answer (score 0):

Instagram **doesn't support multistream** in a post(Feed). Just Reels or Stories.
You can see the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/) for the Feed.
And [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories) for the Stories.

My realization for **multiple images** for **Reels** and **Stories**

```
try {
      val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE)
      share.type = "image/*" //For a video "video/*"
      share.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, listUri)
      share.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION

      context.startActivity(
            Intent.createChooser(
                share,
                context.getString(R.string.share)
          )
      )
} catch (e: Exception) {
       //Not installed Instagram open GP or dialog
}
```

For the **Feed with one Image**

```
try {
      val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
      share.type = "image/*" //For a video "video/*"
      putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
      share.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION

      context.startActivity(
            Intent.createChooser(
                share,
                context.getString(R.string.share)
          )
      )
} catch (e: Exception) {
       //Not installed Instagram open GP or dialog
}
```

The way for the send to Instagram Feed images.
You need to save all images in a gallery and send a single photo to Instagram and  a user chooses images himself

And additional help to get Uri from a remote image with Glide
Also, copy text to the clipboard

```
 Glide.with(context)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(imageUrl)
        .skipMemoryCache(true)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                getLocalBitmapUri(resource)?.let {
                    createInstagramIntent(it)
                }
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
        })
    val clipboard = context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager?
    val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", message)
    clipboard?.setPrimaryClip(clip)


fun getLocalBitmapUri(bmp: Bitmap): Uri? {
    return try {
        val bmpUri: Uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            val file = File(
                context.filesDir.path,
                "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"
            )
            
            FileOutputStream(file)
                .use {
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, it)
                }
            
            FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.packageName + ".fileprovider", file)
        } else {
            val file = File(
                context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"
            )
            
            FileOutputStream(file).use {
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, it)
            }
            
            Uri.fromFile(file)
        }
        bmpUri
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}
```