# Posting Multiple Images to Instagram using Intents

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

Instagram allows a single image or video to be uploaded programmatically from an Android app via Android Intents. I have been able to do this successfully. What I want to know is it possible for Instagram to handle multiple images using Intents? Not much to no information on this unfortunately. The following is my last attempt which opens Instagram briefly then closes with a toast message saying "Unable to load image".

Have tried both Intent.ACTION_SEND and Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE

```
val fileUris = ArrayList<Uri>()

val newFile = File("/data/user/0/com.myapp.android/files/media/961087022.jpg")
val contentUri = getUriForFile(this, "com.myapp.fileprovider", newFile)

grantUriPermission("com.instagram.android", contentUri, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
fileUris.add(contentUri)

val newFile2 = File("/data/user/0/com.myapp.android/files/media/961146948.jpg")
val contentUri2 = getUriForFile(this, "com.myapp.fileprovider", newFile2)

grantUriPermission("com.instagram.android", contentUri2, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
fileUris.add(contentUri2)

val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
shareIntent.type = "image/*"
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUris)
shareIntent.`package` = "com.instagram.android"
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share to"))
```

Comment: Make sure image selection is done from same folder which you used for single image upload. If it's not the case then it's probably issue of Uri. Work around can be use of foreach(...) loop to upload images 1 by 1

Comment: Also, try ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE instead of ACTION_SEND

Comment: @VVB As mentioned in my question I have tried both. ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE is not supported by Instagram unfortunately.

Comment: @VVB  Also in response to your first comment, have checked URIs and they are fine. Uploading 1 by 1 will create multiple posts which we don't want to do. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Not sure but check once whether System raises RuntimeException. If so, then you should use Bundle instead of Parcelable or Serializable. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Comment: This appears to be a similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886407/why-does-instagram-on-android-not-accept-intent-action-send-multiple

Comment: Multiple images support Reels and Stories only
Just see [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75185416/7138808)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking on how to share multiple video files to instagram stories.. I couldn't find how to do it reading the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/#sharing-to-facebook-stories).

Instead i set the intent to send multiple files and set the intent package to "com.instagram.android", and surprisingly it worked..

```
  Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) ;
                            share.setType("video/*");
                            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "abc");
                            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "abcd");

                            ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();

                            for (String path : filesToSend) {
                                File myFiles = new File(path);
                                Uri doneUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext()),
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", myFiles);
                                files.add(doneUri);
                            }

                            share.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
                            share.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
                            startActivity(share);
```

Hope, this helps!!